# opengl color conversion / or SDI signal conversion?

Tags: opengl, colors

- I draw in opengl with RGBA colors these texts (with the color between parenthesis) :
  RED-alpha50 (255,0,0,50) RED-alpha128 (255,0,0,128) RED-alpha255 (255,0,0,255)
  GREEN-alpha50 (0,255,0,50) GREEN-alpha128 (0,255,0,128) GREEN-alpha255 (0,255,0,255)
  BLUE-alpha50 (0,0,255,50) BLUE-alpha128 (0,0,255,128) BLUE-alpha255 (0,0,255,255)
- I memcpy in the buffer (getByte) of a frame created with the format bmdFormat8BitBGRA
  at the size of 1280 pixels by 720 pixels,
  and then send it to the SDI output of a video capture card.
- Here are links to screenshot of what we see on the TV set :
  Channel A (should be the fill : so we expect RGB values)
  [Heberger image http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_444718SDIChA.jpg](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=444718SDIChA.jpg)

Channel B (should be the key : so we expect grey-scale values)

[Heberger image http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_449411SDIChB.jpg](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=449411SDIChB.jpg)

I am not sure which color conversion I should try.

=> Can someone give me hint or working tracks for why the background which should be black is a "half" green (I reckon it to be green with 50% alpha : 0,255,0,128 or else in YUV) ?

=> Is it a question of unsigned byte vs byte : why do I obtain black with (255,0,0,128) and red with (255,0,0,255) : why is the red range reached with alpha between 128 and 255 ?
(but green gets whiter at (0,255,0,255) and blue is a little greenish at (0,0,255,128)).

=> is it a question of converting SDI to HDMI or a HDCP issue ?

Thanks to all for any help,
I am a bit dazzled, and quite new to color conversion,
any help will be so great,
cheers,

Comment: Is this an OpenGL problem or a hardware problem?  Narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok : found : it was a hardware problem : the SDI to HDMI converter we were using only accepts 4:2:2 sampled signal. And we were supplying a 4:4:4 signal. So with the 4:2:2 signal no more green background : we do have grey-scaled values for alpha channel and the fill on the other channel